# How do i get a UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass to use resize with autolayout?

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I'm using Nibs with my tableview for the header and cell

```
  tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "catcell")
  tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CategoryHeaderCell", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "catheader")
```

and setting up autolayout in the storyboard. theres a label and uiswitch aligned to each side.

I'm not getting contstraint errors, before someone suggests [Correct subclassing and autolayout of UITableViewHeaderFooterView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110491/correct-subclassing-and-autolayout-of-uitableviewheaderfooterview) as a solution.

The problem is that the header cell is not filling the tableview, while the normal cell is. You can see a shortened header view below.

[image: screenshot]

in my header subclass, ive tried a few things but they dont work.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    .....
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth  // this doesnt help

    self.setWidth(414)
    self.contentView.setWidth(414)   // none of these change the size
}
```

Comment: reload tablview in viewWillLayoutSubviews method

Comment: Did you even try your solution before to suggest it?

Comment: @zeb yes i did try it